# Extact Job on BigQuery doesn't ensure files on Google Storage

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm executing an extract query to google storage as follows:

```
job_config = bigquery.ExtractJobConfig()
job_config.compression = bigquery.Compression.GZIP
job_config.destination_format = (bigquery.DestinationFormat.CSV)
job_config.print_header = False
job_config.field_delimiter = "|"

extract_job = client.extract_table(
            table_ref,
            destination_uri,
            job_config=job_config,
            location='us-east1', 
            retry=query_retry,
            timeout=10)  # API request
        extract_job.result()
```

Which returns an ExtractJob class and, by the google documentation  (https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/1.24.0/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.ExtractJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.ExtractJob),
I need to call extract_job.result() to wait the job to complete. After the completion, I notice that the files on Google Cloud Storage are not there (yet), maybe there's a delay. I need to ensure that the files are ready to consume after the extraction job, there's a API method to solve this or I have to make a workaround sleeping and waiting the files?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't API for that. You need to poll the file to be sure that they are present before continuing. You can also, if you can in your design, react on Cloud Storage event and perform your processing on that events.

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing as your `destination_uri`? This should be an list of strings, but because you used singular uri in the parameter it sounds like you might be passing a single string which would be misinterpreted (`"gs://abc/def"` would be treated like `["g","s","/","/","a"...]`)

This should cause an error though, did you get an exception?

Comment: I'm passing this parameter because the job is extracting one file but it uses the wildcard -*. In GCP if your file will be larger than 1GB he splits in shards like file-00000001, file-00000002...

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for your time. I figured out that the python API have the destination_uris attribute in Job classes. This gives me an list of URIs of the files extracted, the count of the list gives me how many files were extracted.